# NFS 4 and 3 at the same time, and tcp and udp

Tags: nfs, nfsv4

I have two servers connected via infiniband, and I am testing NFS performance.  This is on RHEL 7.9.

```
NFS-server  /etc/exports

/data *(rw,no_root_squash)
/ramdisk *(rw,no_root_squash)

# exportfs -s

/data    (sync,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,secure,no_root_squash)
/ramdisk (sync,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,secure,no_root_squash)

The /ramdisk folder is via   mount -t tmpfs -o size=100G tmpfs /ramdisk

-----------------------------------------

NFS client  # 1
mounts /data as type nfs4 (rw,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,)
does not mount /ramdisk

-----------------------------------------

NFS client  # 1
mounts /data as type nfs4 (rw,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,)
does not mount /ramdisk

-----------------------------------------

NFS client  # 2
also mounts /data as type nfs4 (rw,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,)

I want to mount /ramdisk as vers=4.1 but with proto = udp,  IS THIS POSSIBLE?

How about mounting /ramdisk as vers=3 and proto = udp, is that possible?
```

No matter what I try with the nfs client I cannot get the mount as anything other than `vers=4.1` and `proto=tcp`.  Can an nfs mount of a given export be of different version and proto types?  Or are those two items locked in on the export side at the nfs-server?

My `/data` export is in use so I don't want to mess with that if I don't have to.  *It used to be that I could never get version 4 working with proto=tcp, now that I do the one time I want to go back I can't and it's p1ssing me off.*

Comment: Did you try to specify the `vers=` parameter yourself? Also mind [`CONFIG_NFS_DISABLE_UDP_SUPPORT`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NFS_DISABLE_UDP_SUPPORT.html) and its description.

Comment: I did try the `vers=` explicity with no luck.  Otherwise all `.conf` files are unmodified and NFS defaults to 4.1 and tcp.  The CONFIG_NFS_DISABLE_UDP states it is in kernel 5.x so I don't think that applies here for RHEL 7.9 with kernel 3.x.